# linux laptop - bind key and click to emulate right click

Tags: linux, laptop, mouse

I have replaced my old iBook with a Asus laptop with Linux Mint.  On that apple, to right click, you would press AppleKey (keyboard key) and click the mouse.  Is there a way to enable similar behavior in Linux?  The Asus laptop has a right click mouse key as well as pressing down with two fingers at the same time which my sister can always do correctly, but they only work correctly about 25% of the time for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config xdotool
```

Then run

```
$ xbindkeys-config
```

and set your chosen key to run the following command

```
$ sleep .2 && xdotool click 3
```

You need to have a wait before `xdotool` clicks due to a bug in one of the programs.